# image and text not aligning properly in twitter tweet timeline using php code

Tags: php, api, twitter, alignment, timeline

am trying to  retrieve the timeline of my twitter home page using php code .when i try to reproduce the timeline the profile pic and tweet text is not aligned properly. when i use float left in the image tag some of the tweets are aligned properly but some of them are misaligned.i am unable to attach the screenshot.i dont want to use javascript.can someone let me know what mistake am making.
i want the profile pic and tweet text side by side.
 html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
if (isset($_GET['user'])) {$user = $_GET['user'];} else {$user = "srini001";}
if (isset($_GET['count'])) {$count = $_GET['count'];} else {$count = 20;}
$getfield = "?screen_name=$user&count=$count";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);

$user_timeurl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
$user_timestring = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($user_timeurl, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);


if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
$x = 1;

echo"test";echo "<br />";
$twet="RT @MercedesAMGF1: Good to see @SChecoPerez and @NicoHulkenberg back in business today. Top work from @ForceIndiaF1 :) #MBFamily #F1";
echo "$twet";echo "<br />";
        $txt = preg_replace('/@(\S+)/i', '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/$1">@$1</a>', $twet);

echo "$txt";echo "<br />";

foreach($string as $items)
    {
        echo "text";"<br/>";
        $tw = $items['text'];



        echo "$x"; echo "<br />";
        echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
        echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
        echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
        echo "Followers: ". $items['user']['followers_count']."<br />";
        echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br />";
        echo "Listed: ". $items['user']['listed_count']."<br /><hr />";
        $x=$x +1;
    }
?>
<div class="blok">
    <h1>html</h1>
    <?php
    foreach($string as $items)
    {
                $tw = $items['text'];
                $screen_name = $items['user']['screen_name'];
                $prof_img = $items['user']['profile_image_url'];
                $txt = preg_replace('/http:\/\/(\S+)/i', '<a href="http://$1">http://$1</a>', $tw);
                $txt = preg_replace('/https:\/\/(\S+)/i', '<a href="http://$1">https://$1</a>', $txt);

                $txt = preg_replace('/#(\S+)/i', '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/#$1">#$1</a>', $txt);
                                //echo "$txt"; echo "<br />";

                $txt = preg_replace('/@(\S+)/i', '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/$1">@$1</a>', $txt);


                ?>
                <div ><img style="float:left"  src = "<?= $prof_img ?> "/><?= $txt ?></div>
                <br/>

<?

    }
?>
</div>

<div class="blok">
    htmltest

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my css code:

```
.blok{
    display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, "Segoe UI", Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-color: #eee #ddd #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;
  max-width: 468px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.blok p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.blok a {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0 none;
}

.blok a:hover,
blockquote.twitter-tweet a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### i updated the css to below:

```
.line{    
    height: 60px;
    margin-left:65px;

  }

  .twprof{
    height: 60px;
    float: left;

  }
```

### also i updated the html code to below:

```
<div class="twprof" ><img src = "<?= $prof_img ?> "/></div><div class="line" ><b><?= $screen_name ?> : </b><?= $txt ?></div>
```

it works fine now.